# Error in taking TPM ownership "invalid TCTI, see --help"

Tags: ubuntu, tpm

on Ubuntu 18.04, I installed TPM2 tools for my TPM operations using `sudo apt-get install tpm2-tools`

I tried to take ownership using below command

`tpm2_takeownership -o password -e password -l password -T device:/dev/tpm0`

Here am trying to specify my TPM device using TCTI-OPTIONS as given in man page of `tpm2_takeownership`. But I am getting error as

`$:invalid TCTI, see --help`

If I remove `-T` option from command line then i get error as

`Failed to initialize tcti context: 0x1`

Comment: Please provide more information. You can elevate the logging level: `TSS2_LOG=tcit+trace tpm2_...` as documented in the [TSS project](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss/blob/master/doc/logging.md)

Comment: now its started working with below command 
`tpm2_takeownership -o password -e password -l password -T device`. This was suggested in below link https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/issues/603